# Move comment-area into content-area

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget, comments

Note: at the bottom of this post I have just added an update. The comments in the update may make some parts of the original post redundant. 
Eventually I want to have a comment section on all my pages. At the moment I just have comments activated on some pages.

I do not have comments activated on this page http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/how-to-back-up-photos-when-abroad/

I do have comments activated on this page http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/blue-moutnains-and-katoomba-nsw/

When I activate comments the FB plugin moves from the right side of the screen to the bottom of the page. How can I prevent this? I altered the width of the comment area and got the comment area to float left and that did not solve my problem. I also got rid of the "clear:both" text and that did not solve the issue. I have now put the "clear:both" text back in my code.

When there are no comments the widget-area is within site-content.

[image]

When there are comments the widget area gets moved. How can I prevent this? Is this causing the issue?

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The comment area code is

```
`/* =Comments */

.comments-area {
margin: 24px auto 0;
border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}

.comments-title,
#respond h3 {
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 1.36em;
color: #999;
}
.comments-title small,
.comment-reply-title small {
float: right;
}

.comment-list,
.comment-list .children {
list-style: none;
}

.comment-list {
margin: 0;
}

.comment-list > .comment:first-of-type {
padding-top: 0;
border-top: 0;
}

.comment {
margin-top: 26px;
padding-top: 27px;
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.comment-meta {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.comment-meta a {
color: #666;
}
.comment-meta .comment-author img {
float: left;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.comment-meta .comment-author .fn {
display: block;
font-weight: normal;
margin-left: 74px;
text-transform: none;
}
.bypostauthor > article .fn:after {
content: "\f304";
font-size: 16px;
left: 3px;
position: relative;
top: -5px;
}
.comment-meta .comment-metadata {
font-size: .8125em;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 2.09231em;
margin-bottom: 27px;
margin-left: 74px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #999;
}
.comment-meta .comment-metadata a {
color: #999;
}
.comment-meta .comment-metadata a:hover {
color: #1c7c7c;
}

.comments-area .edit-link:before {
display: inline;
margin: 0 7px;
content: ' ~ ';
}

.comment-form label {
display: inline-block;
width: 109px;
}

.required {
color: #1c7c7c;
}

.comment-form-author,
.comment-form-email,
.comment-form-url,
.comment-form-comment {
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 27px;
}
.comment-form-author label,
.comment-form-email label,
.comment-form-url label,
.comment-form-comment label {
font-size: .8125em;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 2.09231em;
position: absolute;
top: 7px;
left: 0;
padding: 7px 14px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.comment-form-author input,
.comment-form-email input,
.comment-form-url input,
.comment-form-comment input {
display: block;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 27px;
padding-left: 100px;
}
.comment-form-author textarea,
.comment-form-email textarea,
.comment-form-url textarea,
.comment-form-comment textarea {

width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 27px;
padding: 54px 14px 7px;
}

.says {
display: none;
}

.form-allowed-tags {
color: #999;
}

.no-comments {
font-style: italic;
margin: 27px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #999;
}
```

The index.php code is

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.

 *
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">



        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php penscratch_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The comments.php code is

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form.
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
 * return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">



    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'penscratch' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'penscratch' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '< Older Comments', 'penscratch' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments >', 'penscratch' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 60
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'penscratch' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '< Older Comments', 'penscratch' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments >', 'penscratch' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'penscratch' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>



</div><!-- #comments -->
```

UPDATE - I altered the bottom of the index .php

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then I messed around with the comment area in the IE developer tools. It became apparent that the comment area was part of the side bar or / and widget area. When I changed the width of the comment area to 200px it moved to the right hand side of the content as opposed to underneath it.

Then using IE developer tools I moved  the comment area so it was nested in content - area. Then both the comment area and FB plugin appeared how I wanted them to appear.

How do I alter my code to get the comment-area to be permanently nested in content-area?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a css issue, it seems like a plugin (possibly) is altering the way that the content blocks are being rendered.  Can disable all plugins and take a look at the post with comments and see if everything works correctly?

Comment: I disabled all the plugins minus the few crucial ones such as Akismet and unfortunately it had no affect :(

Comment: How are those images being added? Can you activate comments on another test post with some dummy text and link it.

Comment: Here you go http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/test124/

Answer (score 0):

The widget area of the template you are using is set to be below the comments. Rather than focusing on moving the comments, you may want to explore the template structure where the widget area is.

In the CSS I see this code for the widget area:

```
.site-content .widget-area {
    margin-top: 27px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    .site-content .widget-area {
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 28%;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-top: 0;
    }
}
```

You said:

> Then both the comment area and FB plugin appeared how I wanted them to
>   appear.

Do you have a screenshot of how you want them to appear? It will certainly help in finding a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the blue mountains page was using the page.php template file as oppose to the index.php file.

Then after lots of experimentation I got it working by  altering the bottom of the page.php template file to the below

Before the modifications the sidebar.php was outside of the primary div and the code related to the comments was inside the primary div.

This is what the code looks like after the modification

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code you posted.  I added the  closing tag and moved the comments code above it, that's where you need to place it to be the same width of the primary div.

Also get_sidebar renders a secondary div that needs to sit side-by-side with the primary div in order for it to float next to it. I used firebug to modify the code and attached a screenshot to clarify that's what you're looking for.

```
<?php

if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
 comments_template();
 endif;
?>

  </main>

</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]